# How to execute trap only on the termination of the entire script in ksh on AIX 5.3?

Tags: shell, compatibility, ksh

I want a trap to be executed only when the entire shell script terminates. I wrote the following shell script.

```
foo()
{
    echo begin foo
    trap 'echo TRAP' EXIT
    echo end foo
}

bar()
{
    echo begin bar
    echo end bar
}

foo
bar
```

On an AIX 5.3 system I have, it produces the desired output in bash and ksh93. The trap is the very last thing to be executed in the examples below.

```
# bash foo.sh
begin foo
end foo
begin bar
end bar
TRAP

# ksh93 foo.sh
begin foo
end foo
begin bar
end bar
TRAP
```

But on ksh, the trap is executed when the function `foo` exits.

```
# ksh foo.sh
begin foo
end foo
TRAP
begin bar
end bar
```

What can I do to execute my trap only on the termination of the script in ksh?

Comment: Declare it outside the function.

Comment: Why do you need to run your script under so many different shells? If it produces the desired result in *ksh93* and *bash*, why not stick with one of those interpreters?

Comment: To run a script under *ksh93*, *bash*, and *ksh88* is a little bit like running a C program through a C++ compiler. Some things may work, and some things may break. *ksh88* and *ksh93* implements roughly the same core language, but there are differences. See the list here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/ksh/ksh-13/ksh/src/cmd/ksh93/COMPATIBILITY

Answer (score 1):

The scoping of functions have changed between *ksh88* (*ksh* on your AIX system presumably) and *ksh93*. Quoting [this list of differences between the two shells](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/ksh/ksh-13/ksh/src/cmd/ksh93/COMPATIBILITY):

> Functions, defined with `name()` with *ksh-93* are compatible with    the
>   POSIX standard, not with *ksh-88*.  No local variables are    permitted,
>   and there is no separate scope.  Functions defined    with the `function`
>   name syntax, maintain compatibility.  This also affects function
>   traces.